# CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt

Tags: mysql, cmake

When Im installing mysql I get below errors.

```
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:130 (INCLUDE):
  include could not find load file:

    maintainer


CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:152 (INCLUDE):
  include could not find load file:

    character_sets


CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:154 (INCLUDE):
  include could not find load file:

    ssl


CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:155 (INCLUDE):
  include could not find load file:

    readline


CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:156 (INCLUDE):
  include could not find load file:

    mysql_version


CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:157 (INCLUDE):
  include could not find load file:

    libutils


CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:158 (INCLUDE):
  include could not find load file:

    dtrace


CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:159 (INCLUDE):
  include could not find load file:

    plugin


CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:160 (INCLUDE):
  include could not find load file:

    install_macros


CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:161 (INCLUDE):
  include could not find load file:

    install_layout


CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:162 (INCLUDE):
  include could not find load file:

    mysql_add_executable


CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:258 (INCLUDE):
  include could not find load file:

    configure.cmake


CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:265 (MYSQL_CHECK_ZLIB_WITH_COMPRESS):
  Unknown CMake command "MYSQL_CHECK_ZLIB_WITH_COMPRESS".


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
```

Comment: Your question is incomplete, downvoting. What version of MySQL, CMake, what OS etc. What have you tried? What actually let to the error output?

Answer (score 0):

Set `CMAKE_MODULE_PATH` to the appropriate directory with files `maintainer.cmake`, etc.

And post your source code, of course!